# WAN IP not reachable in LAN

Tags: networking, lan, ip, dd-wrt

I'm running DD-WRT and not being able to reach my public WAN IP from any device on my LAN even though it's visible from outside. Is there some switch I'm missing in DD-WRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
insmod ipt_mark
insmod xt_mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i ! `get_wanface` -d `nvram get wan_ipaddr` -j MARK --set-mark 0xd001
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0xd001 -j MASQUERADE
```

to **Administration** -> **Commands** and **Save Firewall** solved the issue. Discussed in more detail [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=89353) and the bug report [here](http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/ticket/1868).

Answer (score 2):

Under the "Security" section, "Firewall" subsection, uncheck "Filter WAN NAT Redirection".

According to the docs, enabling this option "prevents hosts on LAN from using WAN address of router to contact servers on the LAN (which have been configured using port redirection)."

[image]

Comment: It all makes sense, but it was not checked and whether checked or unchecked, no difference. I found out [a bug report](http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/ticket/1868) which could explain the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have DD-WRT here to give you a full guide on how to enable it, but, this feature is known as "Nat Loopback" and a quick Google shows me that DD-WRT fully supports this.

I am not sure where the option is, but, it will most likely be under NAT/firewall configuration or interface configuration.